# Referential integrity constraint violation. A Dependent Role has multiple principals with different values

Tags: entity-framework

I get the following error when I add more than one entity to a dbcontext in EF6.0, if i only add the first, it saves perfectly, if i add a second one then I get the error.

Error:

> "Referential integrity constraint violation. A Dependent Role has multiple principals with different values."

Code

```
using (var context = new ListingLocatorContext())
{
    var listing1 = new Listing
    {
        UserID = 1,
        ListingDate = DateTime.Now,
        ExpiryDate = DateTime.Now,
        Address = string.Empty,
        PostalCode = string.Empty,
        IsApproved = true,
        CityID = 71,
        IsTop = true,
        IsActive = true,
        ViewCount = 0
    };

    listing1.ListingTypes.Add(new ListingType
    {
        TypeID = 4
    });

    var listing2 = new Listing
    {
        UserID = 1,
        ListingDate = DateTime.Now,
        ExpiryDate = DateTime.Now,
        Address = string.Empty,
        PostalCode = string.Empty,
        IsApproved = true,
        CityID = 71,
        IsTop = true,
        IsActive = true,
        ViewCount = 0
    };

    listing2.ListingTypes.Add(new ListingType
    {
        TypeID = 5
    });

    context.Listings.Add(listing1);
    context.Listings.Add(listing2);

    context.SaveChanges();
}
```

DB Diagram

[image]

Answer (score 1):

Try replacing those two statements:

```
listing1.ListingTypes.Add(new ListingType {
    TypeID = 4
});
```

and

```
listing2.ListingTypes.Add(new ListingType {
    TypeID = 5
});
```

with

```
var listingType1 = new ListingType {
    TypeID = 4,
    Listing = listing1
};
var listingType2 = new ListingType {
    TypeID = 5,
    Listing = listing2
};

context.ListingTypes.Add(listingType1);
context.ListingTypes.Add(listingType2);
```

Comment: That worked for the given example, however my code is a little more complex than that.

Comment: I try to add all new entities to the corresponding context data set explicitly to avoid problems with assumptions

Comment: You should include more of your complex code if you seek more complete answers

Comment: complete code posted.. I was hoping that simplifying the problem will fix my big problem but that only fixed the simple problem, anyways code is posted and same error.  Appreciate your time and effort Kris.