# "Referential integrity constraint violation. A Dependent Role has multiple principals with different values."

Tags: entity-framework

I previously posted issue [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20833522/referential-integrity-constraint-violation-a-dependent-role-has-multiple-princi/20833637?noredirect=1#comment31246309_20833637), however after deeper investigation I have came to the conclusion that the problem is actually related to a association i create between a view and a table.

I have attached a sample solution that contains runable solution to demonstrate the problem, which can be found [here](http://www.filedropper.com/referentialerror).

Steps taken to create the sample code.

1. Create database and run the TSQL Script script to generate objects(script inside the solution zip)
2. Created a .emdx then added all the entities, including the vListing view
3. Created a new association as seen here
   [image]
4. Modified the .emdx manually to only have ListingID as primary key instead of ListingID and Name (this has to be done manually so a constraint can be created because EF designer is buggy when picking what should be a primary key on a view
5. constraint is created as seen below

[image]

After running the code both Test1 and Test2 method will fail, so it doesn't matter if adding children directly to context or entity.

UPDATE:(code did not work)

```
class Program
{
    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        Test1();
        Test2();

    }
    private static void Test2()
    {
        var listings = new List<Listing>();

        for (int i = 0; i < 10; i++)
        {
            var listing = new Listing
            {
                ListingID = i,

                Name = "Name " + i.ToString()
            };
            listing.ListingTypes.Add(new ListingType
            {
                Listing = listing,
                TypeID = 1
            });


            listings.Add(listing);
        }

        using (var context = new ReferentialErrorContext())
        {
            context.Listings.AddRange(listings);

            context.SaveChanges();
        }
    }
    private static void Test1()
    {
        var listings = new List<Listing>();
        var types = new List<ListingType>();
        for (int i = 0; i < 10; i++)
        {
            var listing = new Listing
            {
                ListingID = i,
                Name = "Name " + i.ToString()
            };
            var type = new ListingType
            {
                Listing = listing,
                TypeID = 1
            };
            types.Add(type);

            listings.Add(listing);
        }

        using (var context = new ReferentialErrorContext())
        {
            context.Listings.AddRange(listings);
            context.ListingTypes.AddRange(types);
            context.SaveChanges();
        }

    }


}
```

Comment: As you already pointed, there is another question about the same problem. Did you consider deleting the previous one?

Comment: could not delete it, I flagged it for moderators

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I poked around and it seems to be a legitimate bug in EF. I wrote more details in [the bug you created](https://entityframework.codeplex.com/workitem/1954). I found a work around which is to set the values of `Listing.ListingID` properties of the entities being added to unique values (so you can always start counting from 0 and increment the value for new entities - then you can reset to 0 after calling SaveChanges() or you can keep counting since the value does not really matter as long as it is unique for entities being saved). This should not have any side effects since the property is marked with `StoreGeneratedPattern="Identity"` so the value will be overridden by the value generated by the database anyways.

Just in case here is the code snippet:

```
var listing = new Listing
{
    ListingID = i, // this is the line I added
    Name = "Name + i.ToString()
};
```

**EDIT**

Apparently there is more weirdness going on there. In addition to having to set the ListingId the Listing had to be added to the context before the related entities are added to the context and the related entities cannot be added explicitly. I rewrote the `Test2()` as follows:

```
private static void Test2()
{
    using (var context = new ReferentialErrorContext())
    {
        for (var i = 0; i < 10; i++)
        {
            var listing =
                context.Listings.Add(
                    new Listing
                    {
                        ListingID = i,
                        Name = string.Format("Name {0} {1}", DateTime.Now, i)
                    });

            listing.ListingTypes.Add(new ListingType
            {
                ListingTypeID = i,
                Listing = listing,
                TypeID = 1
            });

        }

        context.SaveChanges();
    }
}
```

and it seems to work - no exceptions are thrown and data is added to the database.

Comment: proposed solution did not work, since i couldnt post all the code in this comment I added the code to initial question

Comment: Indeed I found a workaround using a slightly modified code and assumed it would also work for the original code. Posted the modified `Test2()` that works on my box.

Comment: Thanks for the update, however having a context open while i gather my items is not ideal, since the bug is open with the EF team do you think they will provide a fix any time soon or should I try and make it work with the workaround?

Comment: @Zoinky - I don't know when it will be fixed but I don't believe it will make a cut for EF 6.1.